# Why did Jimmy leave the Frank's room door slightly open?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, the-irishman

In [The Irishman (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Irishman), Jimmy tells Frank a war philosophy:

> Jimmy: In a war, you go from point A to point B. Sometimes, you spill
>   a little beer along the way. That philosophy make sense to you?
>
> Frank: Sure does.

And then Jimmy left Frank's room with the doors slightly open.

[image]

So why did Jimmy leave Frank's room door slightly open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Collider](https://collider.com/the-irishman-ending-explained/) analysed it pretty well:

> The open door recalls an earlier scene in the movie where Frank is
>   staying in Jimmy’s hotel room, and when Jimmy goes to bed he leaves
>   the bedroom door open. It’s not an invitation—there’s nothing to
>   suggest that Frank or Jimmy have romantic feelings towards each
>   other—but it seems more psychological for Jimmy. The way the scene
>   reads is that Jimmy, aware that he has plenty of enemies, is leaving
>   the door open as means of self-defense. Literally and metaphorically,
>   he doesn’t want the door shut on him. He doesn’t want to be boxed in
>   and trapped by his enemies, but leaving the door open also gives him a
>   vague sense of power. It’s an escape route of sorts. If you just leave
>   the door open, you’re no longer trapped, although the sad irony of
>   this scene is that in this moment Jimmy is trusting his protection to
>   his future killer, Frank. robert-de-niro-the-irishman
>
> For Frank to leave his own door open at the end is loaded with
>   meaning. It’s a symbol of regret for killing Jimmy by mimicking his
>   friend’s behavior, but it also speaks to the frailty of both men.

Comment: What's the meaning of that war philosophy?